# Stackdriver - "Publish Message Operations" metric for PubSub topic is not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver

I'm trying to create an alert policy for Publish Message Operations in PubSub. Unfortunately this metric is not available in the project where I have the topics. I can select this metric in other projects though. I can only see 4 metrics depicted in the image below:

[image].

That's how I expect it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider what the documentation says about [project usage attribution](http://cloud/pubsub/quotas#project_usage_attribution):

> For the following quotas, usage is charged against the project associated with the caller's credentials, not against the project that contains the requested resource (that is, the project that appears in the topic or subscription name):
>
> - Publisher throughput
> - Subscriber throughput
> - Administrator operations

So, the project containing the topics might not have a publish message operation count, if that's not the project associated with the credentials of the caller of the Publish RPC.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I've found is after I create another topic and publish into it using credentials associated with the project, all metrics appeared in Stackdriver. Including "publish message operations" for the topics to which I publish with credentials not associated with the project.

Comment: I'm not sure if the root cause of missing metrics was because I published from another project or because those topics were created before I enabled Stackdriver.